# Java: ClassNotFound Classpath issues

Tags: java, jvm, classpath, classnotfound

Im trying to read some information from a file into some objects. Main method just reads the Information into some string variables then uses those strings to initialize objects. Pretty simple. The objects are stored using a BST.

However, The error Im getting is `ClassNotFoundException`. Except when I run the `java 'file'` command, 'file' is spelled and capitalized correctly.

I've been reading that you can change the path that JVM uses when searching for class files.

so I tried:

`set CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH=~/../../BackEnd`

but that didn't do anything..

Here is my main file..

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
class BackEnd
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.FileNotFoundException 
    {


        Tree.ServiceTree providers = new Tree.ServiceTree();
        String path = "./providers.txt";
        Scanner read = new Scanner (new File(path));    
        read.useDelimiter(",");
        String information[] = new String[5];//array of strings used to store info from file, then used to initialize objects
        try
        {
            while(read.hasNext())
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
                {
                    information[i] = read.nextLine();//read in all the info into the array
                }

                Services.Service newService;//used as dynamic reference to be passed to tree
                Services.Service serviceInfo = new Services.Service(information[0], information[1]);//initalizes base class to be passed to derived constructor

                switch(information[0])//check type to initalize appropriate object
                {   
                    case "Dogwalk":
                        newService = new Services.Dogwalk(serviceInfo, information[2], information[3]);
                    case "Groceries":   
                        newService = new Services.Groceries(serviceInfo, information[2], information[3]);
                    case "Housework":
                        newService = new Services.Housework(serviceInfo, information[2], information[3]);
                }
                providers.insert(information[4], newService);
            }
            read.close();
            throw new java.io.FileNotFoundException("File not found...");
        }
        catch(java.io.FileNotFoundException exception)
        {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
        //providers.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the java command's -cp option?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Error had nothing to do with compilation or class path and was due 
to uninitialized variable `newService`

Comment: Which IDE are u using? It should have shown that compilation error saying "Variable 'newService' might not have been initialized"